# How to convert letters to numbers in this set?

Tags: python, set

I'm working on a code that takes as input the last four digits of a phone number as letters then outputs the entire phone number with numbers, but I'm struggling with the conversion process, as it doesn't spit back out the numbers as it's supposed to. Here's my code so far.

```
def reversephone():
    num = input("What's your phone number?: ")
    characters = {2: "abc", 3: "def", 4: "ghi", 5: "jkl", 6: "mno", 7: "pqrs", 8: "tuv", 9: "wxyz"}
    number = " "
    number += num[0:6]
    print(number)
print(reversephone())
```

I'm a beginner to python, so thanks in advance.

Comment: `num` has strings like `"2"` and you would have to conver to integet `int("2")` but better use strings in dictionary `{"2": "abc"`, ...`

Answer (score 0):

the num is a var of string.characters[int(num[i])] can take your letter.You wanna convert num to char? But your

Comment: Hey @Tus I would suggest you to write your answer a little more clear.

Answer (score 0):

if you want convert letters to numbers then use dictionary

```
data = {"a": "2", "b": "2", "c": "2", "d": "3", ...}
```

and then you can do

```
for char in num[6:]:
    number += data[char]
```

---

**EDIT:**

Converting `characters` to `data`

```
characters = {2: "abc", 3: "def", 4: "ghi", 5: "jkl", 6: "mno", 7: "pqrs", 8: "tuv", 9: "wxyz"}
data = dict()

for number, letters in characters.items():
     for char in letters:
         data[char] = str(number)

print(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use list comprehension.

```
def reversephone():
    tel_num = input("What's your phone number?: ")
    characters = {2: "abc", 3: "def", 4: "ghi", 5: "jkl", 6: "mno", 7: "pqrs", 8: "tuv", 9: "wxyz"}
    number_as_char = ''.join([characters[int(num)] for num in tel_num])
    print(number_as_char)

reversephone()
```